# Exclude depth from mmenu

Tags: jquery, mmenu

I'm using https://mmenujs.com and would like to bypass a depth of the menu structure when it's displayed as a mobile menu. For example, desktop menu is like this:

```
1. MENU
   a. SUBMENU
      • link v
      • link w
   b. SUBMENU
      • link x
      • link y
      • link z
2. MENU
   a. SUBMENU
      • link v
      • link w
   b. SUBMENU
      • link x
      • link y
      • link z
```

But on mobile (via mmenu.js) I'd like to just show it like this:

```
1. MENU
   • link v
   • link w
   • link x
   • link y
   • link z
2. MENU
   • link v
   • link w
   • link x
   • link y
   • link z
```

Basically using a nested ul with a depth of 3, but bypassing depth #2 so the user doesn't have to do an extra tap to get past the submenus to get to the actual links.

Thanks!

```js
 $('#mobile-nav').mmenu();
```

```html
<nav id="mobile-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">MENU 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">SUBMENU 1A</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">link v</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">link w</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">SUBMENU 1B</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">link x</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">link y</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">link z</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">MENU 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">SUBMENU 2A</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">link v</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">link w</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">SUBMENU 2B</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">link x</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">link y</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">link z</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: added... should've clarified that I'm using https://mmenujs.com here. It takes the nested UL and turns it into a sliding menu where each submenu is on its own screen. Trying to lose the intermediate step so the user just goes from Main Menu > Links instead of Main Menu > Sub-Menu > Links

Answer (score 0):

You can't completely exclude a level like you ask for without doing some serious JS or PHP prior to calling the mmenu plugin.

But there are a couple of classnames you could add to the UL to try and prevent the mmenu plugin from turning it into a panel:

- "NoPanel" : prevents the UL from being turned in to a panel.
- "NoListview" : prevents the UL from being turned in to a listview.
- "mm-listview_inset" : makes the UL appear as a default UL (with bullets).